# Slow loading time for Android App

Tags: android

I searched and I couldn't find a relevant answer to my problem.

Occasionally, my android app is slow in loading. I normally use the back button to close the app. When I start my app again, sometimes, the app takes time to load, especially after its starting other activities from the main activity. I load the new activity using  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

I suspect the activity didn't stop properly by pressing the back button; so, when I relaunch the app at other time I have slow loading. If I force stopped the app before relaunch, it loads immediately.

My question is

1. Should I put `finish()` at the activity when I press back button?
2. I use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to make transition to
   another activity, is that a right flag to use?

Thanks

Comment: The finish() will be called by default when you press back button. not need to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP explicitly. the flag depends on your purpose

Answer (score 2):

Quote for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

This means your activity is not being launched. I suggest you do not use any flags altogether to start activities. But I cannot be sure unless you paste some code and clearly specify what do you want to achieve.

Another note: I doubt you would want to "destroy" your app when a user presses the "back" button. You should leave this at its default too. The virtual machine will destroy your app as necessary.

PS: One of the apps which I supervised as a developer with BetaGlide (a mobile app performance testing tool) had a similar problem and with the above mentioned steps and then measuring the results with betaglide we were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

when you press back button, you can check whether onDestroy() has been invoked, which means your activity is killed or not.

Comment: except to my main activity, most of my activities are google map activities. Is there something to do when working with google map, any idea.

Comment: My program crash when I put onDestroy().

Comment: really? what is the crash log?